# Nvidia driver not compatible with Windows 10 x64

Tags: nvidia-geforce

Need help! I have gtx 650 and all previous windows and nvidia driver works perfect. But with windows 10 no one driver is compatible every driver have random crashes and display noise and lines. Now i have 358.50 problem did not resolve till now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, for a GT 520m.

On [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/3gcpxz/need_help_with_my_nvidia_geforce_gt_520_drivers/), they suggest to use a driver for windows 8, and it might do the trick. For me it didn't

I manage to get the driver working, but it was a long process.

- I use [DDU tool](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/DDU/) to firstly remove the driver in safe mode.
- Then, using [KB3073930](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) I "hide" all related updates to my GPU (either because of the PCI, or because these related to NVIDIA). This step blocks windows to update your nvidia driver.
- I reboot again, and install the WHQL drivers, in safe mode, as an administrator, as fresh install, using the NVIDIA setup files. I tried with the 358.50 WHQL driver.

It didn't recognize the card at first, and after a few reboots it took it.

All in all, I tried to follow this [guide](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/windows-10-how-fix-nvidia-driver-issues-after-upgrade-1513643) to get mine working.

Now, I've been running with this setting for 3 days without problems. I use multiple monitor setting, with a laptop, both monitors are working fine.

Good luck!